# Is there a method like append() for Path in Android?

Tags: java, android, path, append, line

I have a line that I would like to add to a Path but don't see a method similar to `appened` *(in Java one would use GeneralPath.append(new Line2D.double)   )*

For instance, in Java code I have something like:

```
GeneralPath thePlots = new GeneralPath();
thePlots[CONST_INT].append(new Line2D.Double(centerX, centerY, xy[0], xy[1]), false);

//later I draw my line and whatever other points I have
```

However, in Android I don't see the option to append (or Line2D for that matter). Is there an alternative way of doing this rather than using `canvas.drawLine()` and then drawing the rest of the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)?

Comment: That's what I'm referring to, is there a way to append a line to Path :)  - (I'm glad you're constantly willing to help out with Android by the way!)

Comment: You can do `path.moveTo` to set the initial position, then `path.lineTo` for each line you want to add.

Comment: That is what I did in one of my previous questions. I wasn't sure if it would keep track of the initial position though. Lets say I create the Path array in a method but don't draw it until much later, it will keep track of the entire path if I use moveTo? And what becomes of my `centerX` and `centerY` variables?

Comment: Yep: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#moveTo%28float,%20float%29. It moves the beginning of the next line to the new position, but the as long as the original Path object isn't reset you should be fine. And strictly speaking it is a Path, not a Path array :)